# Accesssing Firebase Firestore from a script

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter Andriod app that can be used to store data in the firestore. Now I want to access that stored data from a Dart script to perform some operations on the data.

How can I access the firestore with a Dart script?

**Updated the question**: Looking only for dart package/library to access firebase firestore.

Comment: https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with [firedart](https://pub.dev/packages/firedart).

```
import 'package:firedart/firedart.dart';

String pi = 'example-app';

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  Firestore.initialize(pi);
  var map = await Firestore.instance.collection("users").get();
  print(map);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#python) provides good help with how to set up environment and a lot of examples.

Comment: Yup, thanks but I just realized that since I have already written most of my code in Dart. So looking for a Dart package to reuse that same code instead of rewriting it in Python.

Comment: Here's the doc how to set up Firebase with Flutter: [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios)